# How to open Modal from another component in hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have the requirement of opening Modal from another component. I found suggested questions from StackOverflow but, not yet convinced. As I need to make the Modal component reusable across all components. See the code below for reference

Homepage.js

```
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setLoginModalShow(true)}>Open Modal</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I created the below file to export other files too, and make it useful in other components

commonLogin.js

```
import LoginModal from "./LoginModal";

export const setLoginModalShow = (props) => {
  console.log("PROPS", props);
  return <LoginModal showModal={props} />;
};
```

And here is the Modal component

```
const LoginModal = (props) => {
  const [loginModalShow, setLoginModalShow] = useState(props.showModal);

  console.log("PROPS in MODAL", props);
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        show={loginModalShow}
        onHide={setLoginModalShow}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Logout</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4>Are you sure to Logout?</h4>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={() => setLoginModalShow(false)}>Cancel</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

Please refer to the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-cdn-70zuq.
After you visit the page click on the 'Open Modal' button

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to control the show/hide from the parent component

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowLogin(true)}>Open Modal</button>
      <LoginModal show={showLogin} close={() => setShowLogin(false)} />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<Modal
        show={props.show}
        cancel={props.close}
...
```

Here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-euclid-d0dw0

Comment: Neatly explained, Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @olore thank you very much for your answer, it works like a charm. But I just wonder how does "props.close" work? I didn't understand because we set a function `close={() => setShowLogin(false)}` here. Could you please explain a bit more? I'm newbie in React, sorry. :))

Comment: `close` is a function that gets called by LoginModal that let's HomePage know that the user wants to close the modal. We're passing in a function to tall that will change the state of `showLogin` so that it will no longer display. hth

Comment: Alright, that is the schoolbook example... but what if that `button` is nested within several  components. Am I going to be passing arguments for every possible modal I want down the component structure?

Comment: it sounds like you have a "prop drilling" problem. There are various ways to address it. For example, take a look at https://blog.logrocket.com/solving-prop-drilling-react-apps/